# To 406 or not to 406 (http status code)

Tags: ruby, http, rest, sinatra, http-status-codes

I'm developing a RESTful web application in Ruby with Sinatra. It should support CRUD operations, and to respond to Read requests I have the following function that formats the data according to what the request specified:

```
def handleResponse(data, haml_path, haml_locals)
  case true
  when request.accept.include?("application/json") #JSON requested
    return data.to_json
  when request.accept.include?("text/html") #HTML requested
    return haml(haml_path.to_sym, :locals => haml_locals, :layout => !request.xhr?)
  else # Unknown/unsupported type requested
    return 406 # Not acceptable
  end
end
```

Only I don't know what is best to do in the `else` statement. The main problem is that browsers and jQuery AJAX will accept `*/*`, so technically a `406` error is not really the best idea. But: what do I send? I could do `data.to_s` which is meaningless. I could send what HAML returns, but they didn't ask for `text/html` and I would rather notify them of that somehow.

Secondly, supposing the `406` code is the right way to go, how do I format the response to be valid according to the [W3 spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.7)?

> Unless it was a HEAD request, the response SHOULD include an entity containing a list of available entity characteristics and location(s) from which the user or user agent can choose the one most appropriate. The entity format is specified by the media type given in the Content-Type header field. Depending upon the format and the capabilities of the user agent, selection of the most appropriate choice MAY be performed automatically. However, this specification does not define any standard for such automatic selection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to do a clearing-house method for all the data types you could return, but that can be confusing for the user of the API. Instead, they should know that a particular URL will always return the same data type.

For my in-house REST APIs, I create certain URLs that return HTML for documentation, and others that return JSON for data. If the user crosses the streams, they'll do it during their development phase and they'll get some data they didn't expect and will fix it.

If I had to use something like you're writing, and they can't handle `'application/json'` and can't handle `'text/html'`, I'd return `'text/plain'` and send `data.to_s` and let them sort out the mess. JSON and HTML are pretty well established standards now.

---

Here's the doc for [Setting Sinatra response headers](http://sinatra.rubyforge.org/api/classes/Sinatra/ResponseHelpers.html#M000033).

Comment: That looks like a good answer. Note that on the server I can fully implement what happens on a 406 error, so I could send an error message in `text/plain` rather than the data. This may be the best solution. Can you tell me how I should build the response to include a list of acceptable types as well?

Comment: I'd suggest you rollback your answer to the previous version... If `406` is wrong, `405` is worse because it is about the HTTP method, e.g. `GET`, `POST`, etc...

Comment: Rolled back. The list of acceptable types is going to be a header, and, if I remember right, the Sinatra docs show how to create additional header content.

Comment: according to this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4422980/1313143 - no appropriate header exists. Apparently you should just send a request body with the acceptable types. I have done this in `text/plain` now, and I'll leave it at that. Thanks for your effort.